# Remove working copy with TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, working-copy

When I clone a repository I have the choice of "Do not update the new working directory", which can be nice if I just want a copy of the repo without all the files.

If I did not check that when I cloned it, is there a way to "update" it to that state? Obviously if I just delete all the files, then TortoiseHg will think I have deleted the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click any revision in your changeset list inside TortoiseHg and select Update to, this brings up the update dialog.

Simply enter `00` (double zeroes), this will change the target revision to -1, and when you update to that, you'll have the same state as if you had checked that checkbox during cloning.

Note that if you have added untracked, uncommitted files in the working folder after cloning, those might still be present, so you should either run the `hg purge` afterwards, or just manually delete those.

Comment: can also key in null instead of 00.  from command line hg up null will do the same thing.